# Java, maintain near-constant SQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im in the process of developing a fairly simple yet large scale (in terms of potential Database size) Java application.

**My question is what is the best way to maintain a connection to a MYSQL database? I will be needing to update it every few seconds, but want to do this safely and properly.**

Tips, suggestions, should i not use SQL? If not, then what are some other database options, simple booleans and strings are needed to be stored.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

To anyone who is interested or comes across this question, i've found this example of connection pooling thanks to Nambari's answer:

http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/12/dbcp-connection-pooling-example

Comment: Just choose a good ORM framework with a good transaction manager framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the solutions for your problem would be using [connection pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html). This way you can re-use connections instead of creating everytime.

[Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) is one of the highly used API for this scenario.

Comment: Looks perfect for my needs, did not know about this thank you.